# Use HtmlAgilityPack to select elements without the "id" attribute

Tags: html-agility-pack

I would like to select all **div** elements that doesn't have an **id** attribute. I tried different combinations and Googled quite a bit, but I just can't get it right.

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[!@id]")  <-- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath `not()` to achieve that, for example :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelecteNodes("//div[not(@id)]")
```